# How to efficiently rename many files or partially select the names of these files during import?

Tags: import, rename

how to rename the files efficiently by the number in the name (see picture)? I did not succeed with Windows PowerToys and I dont wana click each file and rename to the number (e.g. 290)

or how to read the files in this order and define a name? If I try it with a script (see below) the following output occurs:

```
[![ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '211001_164357_P_Scripted_Powermeasurement_Wavelength_automatic_Powermeter1_0'][1]][1]
```

or how to select only the numbers (290 to 230 - see picture) within the name when reading?

Script:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

data_location = r'C:\Users\...\Characterization_OPO\Data'
data_folder = Path(data_location)
data = {}

allist = list(data_folder.glob('*'))

for i, file in enumerate(allist):
    file = str(file)
    file_name = file.split('\\')[-1]
    wavelength = int(file_name.split('.')[0])
    tmp = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=20, skipfooter=59, index_col="PixelNo")
    data[f'{wavelength} nm'] = tmp;
    #data.plot(x='Wavelength',y='CCD_1', label=f"{wavelength} nm")
```

Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I removed all words with windows power rename and than took the last three digits:

```
    for i, file in enumerate(allist):
        file = str(file)
        file_name = file.split('\\')[-1]
        wavelength = int(file_name.split('.')[0])
        tmp = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=26, skipfooter=5)
        data[f'{wavelength % 1000} nm'] = tmp;
        #data.plot(x='Wavelength',y='CCD_1', label=f"{wavelength} nm")
```